# Laravel Newsletter Email System

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've seen a tutorial on how to do a newsletter system with a third party plugin using [iron.io](http://www.iron.io/) for Laravel 4. To be able to use the queuing messaging system you have to pay them a monthly service, my question is it necessary to use the third party plugin or can I just simply use the Mail::queue() command to perform the operations at once for each subscriber(is it sufficient enough to do the job).

Comment: native laravel should be just fine

Comment: A newsletter system without a proper service such as mandrillapp.com or alikes will result in many troubles in general for your domain.

Comment: @user2094178 can you please explain why sending emails without any service will cause troubles for the domain ?

Comment: @VinceCarter The domain will get blacklisted in a hurry in the case of newsletter or mass-mailing.

Answer (score 1):

First I think that iron.io has a free plan ... check "Lite (Free)" on  [iron.io/pricing/](http://www.iron.io/pricing/)

Now, regarding to plugins, - no, you do not need to use third party plugins.
Laravel is made to work with different queue types. I have made newsletter system using mandrill in production with beanstalkd. But in my local env I do not have beanstalkd so I am using another configuration.

You can have different configurations for different env ... you can put production configuration for queues in

> app/config/queue.php

and your local dev env configuration in

> app/config/localdev/queue.php

where "localdev" should be replaced with your env name.

In production you can using "***beanstalkd***" and in local env you can use "***sync***".

Here you have article with examples how to setup Beanstalkd: [Production-Ready Beanstalkd with Laravel 4 Queues](http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4)

When you configure beanstald then "Mail::queue" should work.

Anyway,
if you plan to develop newsletter system I recommend you to check mandrill or mailgun. mandrill is cheaper for large volume eemails (More than 40.000 monthly), mailgun gives you 10.000 emails free each month.

I have created demo project on [php-laravel5-newsletter-demo](https://github.com/gandra/php-laravel5-newsletter-demo)  and soon I will finish basic example to have newsletter working with mandrill and mailgu8n.

Comment: Hey I got the queing working for the default 'sync' Queuing option, and I checked out beanstalkd site to install and I can't see how to intall it using git-bash for windows.

Comment: And also where do you put the Queue class file that has the event "fire" function.

Comment: You can not install it on windows. Eventually you can use vagrant to simulate linux env on windows. 
But why to use it on lcoal env ... beanstalkd is fast ine memory queue, aimed to use it in production ... for local dev sync is enough?

Comment: I am working on laravel 4 at the moment and I have in the composer defined:

"psr-4": {
    "EklikApp\\": "app/Eklik"
}

and then I habe put Queue files inside folder: app/Eklik/Queue